# Why is OnGetAsync is not called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

- Both classes are in the same folder. The code in  the Index Model page
  works   for a get request to edit/91 it seems like context is not
  returned back.
  This code does not work in the Pages folder, which is
  strange, because the same code works in the index one

  namespace CalendarApp.Pages
  {
  public class EditModel : PageModel
  {
  private readonly CalendarAppContext _context;
  private readonly CalendarAppContext _context2;

  ```
       public EditModel(CalendarAppContext context, CalendarAppContext context2)
       {
           _context = context;
           _context2 = context2;
       }
       public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
       public CurrentDay today { get; set; }

       public async Task OnGetAsyc(int id)
       {
            today = await _context.CurrentDays.FindAsync(id);


           var activities = from a in _context2.Activities
                            where a.TimeAt.Month == 4
                            select a;

           Activities = await activities.ToListAsync(); }}}
  ```

That is the error:
[image]

Comment: Did you call `OnGetAsync`, which seems to be the only place where you assign something to `Activities`?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry the prepared "activities" go into "Activities"

Comment: I just modified the code

Comment: I thought OnGetAsync is called when I send a get request to /Edit/{id}

Comment: Did you debug your application to verify that it is being called?

Comment: I ran it in debug mode, OnGetAsync never ran. Could it be the parameter maybe? The request is to /Edit/91 but that should work as the page expects @page "/Edit/{id} corrected it now from  "/Edit/{ID}

Comment: So then it turns out your question has changed focus into why `OnGetAsync` isn't called.

Comment: It was a typo (OnGetAsyc), but thanks anyway.

Comment: I know this post is quite old but I just wanted to save anyone from the headache I had recently... 

While converting MVC project .NET Framework to Razor Pages .NET 7, I made a 'MVC thinking' error when instead of referencing `@model IndexModel` in `Index.cshtml` page I've referenced directly my model class (+necessary `@using`)

    @page "{id}"
    @using WBTCore.Models.CustomModels;
    @model AthleteModel

The outcome was, no `OnGet()`/`OnGetAsync()` in corresponding `Index.cshtml.cs` was ever called and page was throwing a null exception for the model.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it is not allowed to iterate over `null` or treat `null` as an object which implements `IEnumerable`.

One possibility might be to use an [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) for a fallback to en empty enumartion of your models.

```
@foreach (var c in Model.Activities ?? Enumerable.Empty<Acitivty>())
{
    // insert code here
}
```

Otherwise, you might try to just ensure that `Model.Activities` is always assigned and never null.

```
public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; } = new List<Activity>();
```

or maybe even

```
public List<Activity> Activities { get; } = new List<Activity>(); // without setter
```

Comment: I tried that, fixes the error, but it looks like OnGetAsync  doesn't run, because all values remain the basic ones.

Comment: It was a typo (OnGetAsyc), but that addition was useful anyway, so thanks.